# Unrecognizable character in C++

Tags: c++, string, parsing, char, ascii

I'm programming an application that converts .txt files to bags of words for text mining. However, I keep getting non-alphabetic characters ( like ¾ and =)  even though my application filters non-alphabetic characters:

My vector passes through a loop which erases strings that begins with a char with an ASCII value other than [65,90] (from A to Z). These characters also pass the *isalpha* test. It seems like these characters can't be distinguished from alphabetic characters.

I don't see how I can remove these weird strings dynamically from my vector of strings. I need help.

My code because it is quite long for a forum post.

This part of my code fails to get rid of the strings beginning with non-aphabetic characters:

```
for (unsigned int i=0; i<token24.size();i++){ 
string temp = token24[i]; 
char c = temp[0];
 if(c>90||c<65){ 
token24.erase(token24.begin()+i);
 i--;
 } 
}
```

I also tried with the condition

```
 (c>'Z'||c<'A')
```

Comment: You'll need to include at least the relevant section of code; it would also help to see an example of the text your code isn't handling properly.

Comment: You should show some real code and explain the logic of your program, for example what is the encoding used to read your files and how you detect that.

Comment: This part of my code fails to get rid of the strings beginning with non-aphabetic characters:

for (unsigned int i=0; i<token24.size();i++){
        string temp = token24[i];
            char c = temp[0];
if(c>90||c<65){
                token24.erase(token24.begin()+i);
       i--;     
}
}

Comment: Please put the code in your post, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could always do a string replace the characters with whitespace, but that just handles the specific cases of specific characters, not the larger problem.

I don't think we can do anything for you until we see the code.

Comment: This doesn't really the answer;  as you point out, there's not enough information to answer it yet.  This should have been posted as a comment.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, not all of us have the level of rep. to comment.  I do provide at least a partial solution.

Comment: Ooo, didn't look at the rep level… Well, hang in there, you'll be up to 50 rep soon (suggesting edits is a quick way to get there, if you're in a hurry).

Comment: No problem, Joshua.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

The most important part in programs like yours is handling the content of .txt file. Such file can be a Unicode text, which in turn can be encoded, for eample, with UTF-8. Then, single byte can be only a part of a character, not character itself. Are you sure you load (and possibly, decode) the file in a proper way?

Also, don't you think that lower letters are also valid alpha characters?

Comment: I've extracted the text files are posts from 4chan that I've extracted automatically through the site's API. I've converted everything to uppercase because I'm interested in the frequency of word occurences. I don't have much knowledge about character codes but I have to learn it to fix this.